# std::set. Custom set of sets

Tags: c++, compare, functor, stdset, equivalence

Word.

I have a struct, containing a single field that I would like set to use for comparison and equivalence, and other fields as metadata:

```
struct read_tag{
    unsigned int read_id; // want std::set to use this
    int offset;           // metadata
    bool orientation;     // metadata
};
```

I have a functor to do the job:

```
struct read_tag_compare {
    bool operator() (const read_tag &a, const read_tag &b) const {
        return a.read_id > b.read_id
    }
};
```

and decl. the required set as

```
std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare> block;
```

Everything so far compiles. The problem is below:

How do I make a set containing `std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare>`. I want something like this:

```
std::set< std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare> > blocks;
blocks.insert(a_block); // comp error
```

But this gives me a very large, and hard to decipher error.

I thought it would recursively check how the inner sets are compared and extend this to the outer sets. All one had to do is define the comparator for the inner most set.

For example

```
std::set<std:set<unsigned int>> set_o_sets;
```

works fine, without me having to define how to compare `std::set<unsigned int>`

Any help is mucho appreciated :D

Comment: No because I want only one `std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare>` in `blocks` defined by the equivalence.

Comment: I dont care if the metadata from the two sets are not equivalent. Becasuse if two sets contains all the same `read_tag`s, in terms of `read_tag.read_id` the metadata is not equivalent in a numerical sense, but the same information can be derived later. So I can take either one of the two sets, but I dont want both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<`-comparison on `std::set` uses `std::lexicographical_compare` without comparator, i.e. it just forwards to `<` on the element type. (This is a limitation of the standard library, since this is defined for all containers, not just the ordered-associative ones.) So what you need is a custom comparator for sets of sets that uses the correct overload of lexicographical comparison:

```
using read_tag_set = std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare>;

struct read_tag_set_compare {
    bool operator()(const read_tag_set &a, const read_tag_set &b) const noexcept {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                            b.begin(), b.end(), a.key_comp());
        //                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

Now use: `std::set<read_tag_set, read_tag_set_compare>`

---

The code shows why there isn't an obvious "fix" to the ordered associative containers that would make this "just work": If the containers use custom, stateful predicates, then it's not in general guaranteed that the members of two distinct containers can actually be compared with one another at all. All you know is that the elements *within* one container are comparable with that container's comparator. So when you're using a custom comparator, you better also say explicitly how two distinct containers relate, and you assert explicitly that it makes sense to compare two containers.

Comment: Sir, you truly are a god among men. Thanks so much! So `a.key_comp()` will "prompt" the use of my `read_tag_compare` functor to perform the comparison between two `std::set<read_tag, read_tag_compare>`s ?

Comment: You nicely explained the problem of custom predicated with user def. types that may make no sense to compare; rather than paring it of as its too ambiguous like "shoe" before he got scared by the down vote...oh SO

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak: We're using a different overload of `lexicographical_compare`, namely the one that takes a predicate. I randomly chose one of the two possible comparators (`a.key_comp()` and `b.key_comp()`), because in your particular case they are interchangeable (they are stateless).

Answer (score 0):

It compiled with no error with my g++-5.3.1 ubuntu..

```
#include<set>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct read_tag{
    unsigned int read_id; // want std::set to use this
    int offset;           // metadata
    bool orientation;     // metadata
};
struct read_tag_compare {
    bool operator() (const read_tag &a, const read_tag &b) const {
        return a.read_id > b.read_id;
    }
};
struct read_compare {
bool operator() (const set<read_tag, read_tag_compare> &a, const     set<read_tag, read_tag_compare> &b) const {
    return true;
}
};

int main()
{
    set<read_tag, read_tag_compare> block;
    set<set<read_tag, read_tag_compare>, read_compare> blocks;
    blocks.insert(block)
}
```

Above was what I compiled.

Comment: I just copy & pasted your code. It compiled fine with no error. How can I show you..?

Comment: In fact, yes, this compiles, it is blocks.insert() that errors.

Comment: Did you just added insert ?

Comment: Conclusion : You have to devise some way of comparing your two sets.

Comment: Your simple `read_compare` works, because its not actually comparing anything. Just returning true. Check accepted answer. `set::insert()` freaked out because it doesn't know how to compare using the `>` operator, a necessity for comparison, when comparing my user defined sets.

Comment: @Parker: You can show it by pasting an example on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) that exercises some representative functionality and that compiles with all the recent compilers. But I understood your original post to mean that "the OP's code compiles with no error"; this is clearly not true, and the code that you now show is different from the OP's code. (It also has undefined behaviour.)

Comment: I mentioned  it above.. I added a functor. I don't know what his intention is about that set... A simple set comparison can be size? return a.size() < b.size(); Would this fit the functionality you seek?

Comment: I am not saying that my functor is well formed. Heed my conclusion please.